# How do I prove p- component is contained in torsion sub module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

[image]        M is a finitely generated module over pid   . consider the ring (Z/p)(x) as a module over itself. It's p component is the entire module. It's  torsion submodule is the zero module. Does this case not contradict the statement in the picture. Forgive the bad presentation. I am posting from a phone

Comment: Presumably the $\ p\ $ in the $\ p$-component has to be a prime *in the pid over which* $\ M\ $ is a module. If that's the case, then I don't understand your example.  The rational functions $\ \left(\mathbb{Z}/p\right)(x)\ $ in $\ x\ $ over $\ \left(\mathbb{Z}/p\right)\ $ form a field, which contains no primes.  So there can be no $\ p$-component of $\ \left(\mathbb{Z}/p\right)(x)\ $ regarded as a module over itself, and then it is vacuously true that all of them are contained in the torsion module.

Comment: thanks. I mistook p to be a prime number